# Syntaxhighlighter inserting extra blank line after each line

Tags: javascript

I use [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) on my blog to format C++ code. Since last few days I am getting  extra blank line after each line after each line of code. Please see this [link](http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/2011/08/find-optimal-number-of-jumps-to-reach.html) for more info.

Following is the code I wrote there. I am not seeing any line break in that.

```
//Define MAX 1 less so that adding 1 doesn't make it 0
#define MAX 0xFFFFFFFE;

unsigned int jump(int *array, int n)
{
    unsigned int *result = new unsigned int[n];
    int i, j;

    //Boundry conditions
    if (n == 0 || array[0] == 0)
        return MAX;

     result[0] = 0;  //no need to jump at first element
     for (i = 1; i &lt; n; i++)
     {
           result[i] = MAX; //Initialization of result[i]
           for (j = 0; j &lt; i; j++)
           {
                 //check if jump is possible from j to is
                 if (array[j] &gt;= (i-j))
                 {
                       //check if better solution available
                       if ((result[j] + 1) &lt; result[i])
                             result[i] = result[j] + 1;  //updating result[i]
                 }
           }
     }

     //return result[n-1]
     unsigned int answer = result[n-1];
     delete[] result;

     return answer;
}
```

Surprisingly this is happening only for new posts, all [old posts](http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/2011/08/convert-binary-tree-in-circular-doubly.html) are shown currently w/o extra blank lines.

Comment: i'd say you added this post from another browser / newer version of the same browser?

Comment: @Naveen: Yes I did, how that might cause extra blank lines? On previewing in blogger it looks ok but after publish it shows empty lines.

Comment: @Akash: the code you paste here is converted to HTML by StackOverflow. That makes it impossible to tell what the original file line feeds looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code (before JavaScript) basically looks like this:

```
<pre>
First line
<br />Another line
<br />Last line
</pre>
```

If you are using a `<pre>` tag, you don't need to insert `<br />` tags to force line feeds but, if you do, they should *replace* the original line feed.

**Update:** I'll make a blind guess with the little information we have. Your code is saved into a local file using Windows line feeds (`CR+LF`). The server runs Linux and applies a function that replaces Linux line feeds (`LF`). with `<br />` tags so you end up with `CR<br />`. This is inserted into a `<pre>` tag so the browser converts this to two consecutive line feeds.

My hypothesis seems likely because, if you save the HTML source code into a file and open it with a text editor that can display line feeds, it'll show the file is using Linux style (`LF`) everywhere expect in the code snippet, where it's using `CR` (old MacOS 9 style).

[image]

Workaround: save the file as Unix before copying *or* copy with another editor *or* copy to another browser.

Comment: @naveen: certainly. The generated source has empty list items to represent empty lines (`<li class=""><span>  </span></li>`) which is correct because *there are* empty lines.

Comment: +1: thats correct. apologies. i inspected the code at mozilla and found br and line feeds. i guess the op is not doing anything differently. thats how the wysiwyg editor behave in his browser.

Comment: On inspecting in firebug etc, I found the same. But I didn't add any empty line. Don't know why these are coming. Any idea.

Comment: On previewing in blogger it looks ok but after publish it shows empty lines.

Comment: @Akash, you have to understand that `<br />` tags don't get appended magically. There must be some server-side code that's inserting them on purpose. You mention [Blogger](http://www.blogger.com). Does it mean that you have no control on your site's code?

Comment: @Álvaro: Thanks! I manually just replace all "\n" with <br/> and it worked. Though I am still confused from where I am getting it. It's not visible in any editor as well.